# How to insert ONLY the date (time not included) to ms access database using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

```
OleDbCommand command3 = new OleDbCommand();
command3.Connection = connection;
command3.CommandText = "INSERT into AddLoad(ID_Number,Load_Added,Load_Date) values (@ID_Number, @Load_Added,@Load_Date)";
command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Number",UserControl_AddLoadConfirmation.INumberValue);
command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Load_Added",addbalance);
command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Load_Date",DateTime.Now.ToString());
command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried changing the format of my date column (Load_Date) in ms access database to "Short Date" format, when I view all datas to my Datagrid, it still comes with the `hour:minute format`.

im not sure with the problem maybe it's this code `DateTime.Now.ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to persist a date or datetime in your database

1. the type in your database should be datetime (not varchar!)
2. You should pass DateTime types to your database directly in the command (not a string equivalent)
3. You should read back a datetime type when querying from the database (not a string equivalent)

So this line

```
command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Load_Date",DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Becomes this

```
command3.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Load_Date", OleDbType.Date) { Value = DateTime.Today });
```

This also ensures that you are passing the correct type to the command so it knows how it is represented in the schema. You really should not call `AddWithValue` as this does not pass that information in to the command.

---

Also keep in mind that when working with Ole (ie. access) parameters are positional and not named. That means the order they appear in in the query has to be  the same order they appear in within the parameter collection.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir. Im still new at C#, 
-ive already changed the format to datetime (im using ms access)
- and, im not trying to input any date from command or something. i just want to insert the date (time not included). Thanks again :)
and this code doesn't work

command3.Parameters.Add(New OleDbCommand("@Load_Date", OleDbType.DateTime) {Value = DateTime.Now};

Comment: @JohnR.deVeyra - are you still running into issues?

Comment: @JohnR.deVeyra - also do not use `shortdate`, just use either `date` or `datetime` and change the `OleDbType` above in the command parameter accordingly.

Comment: @JohnR.deVeyra - i had edited my code (6 min ago). Refresh my answer... It uses `OleDbType.Date` and `System.DateTime.Now.Date` as the value.

Comment: It works :)))))) 
command3.Parameters.Add("@Load_Date", System.DateTime.Now.Date); 
Thank you for your time, I really needed this for my final project. 
And this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow lol, never expected that you guys would reply this fast.
thanks again, have a good one :)

Comment: `DateTime.Today` would be the direct source.